# How can I void a charge in the react-coinbase-commerce component?

Tags: coinbase-api

Whenever I successfully complete a charge from a particular checkout via the CoinbaseCommerceButton component the completion screen shows up when I go to buy a new item. How can I automatically have the screen begin anew when the charge is either successful, or the modal is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version allows you to pass in a prop called **disableCaching** that lets you create new charges every time a checkout is opened. But be aware:

> Warning: If disableCaching is set to true, users that accidentally
>   close their payment windows will be unable to see their transaction's
>   status upon reopening.

Documented in the Readme: https://github.com/coinbase/react-coinbase-commerce